# How to store Japanese character in oracle DB?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to store Japanese(or any language) character in one column of my oracle database table.

I have used varchar2 as data type. when I am trying to insert this character(ꏕ) to this column its stored as '[]'.

Don't know what to do. Need help.

Note:
I tried to change the data type to nvarchar2 still didn't work.

https://translate.google.co.in/?hl=en&tab=wT#auto/en/Kinj%20A%20%CC%88%EA%8F%95%20%C9%82%20%C8%82%20%C4%82%20%E6%82%A9%0A%ED%82%A9%20%C3%84%20%EA%8F%95%20%C9%82%C8%82%C4%82%20%E6%82%A9

Comment: Try to use NLS_LANG=.JA16SJIS and then insert. Also check for the length of column for max length

Comment: Thank you for your replay, Could you please explain more, I mean how I can use this and will it be useful for all languages ? because I have to insert all country languages including Japanese.

Comment: For sure it won't solve the issue for all languages. You have to set the language based on session

Comment: Based on session means? Please let me know how to use this Japanese character.

Comment: Hi, please read this document https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch3globenv.htm, if you have multi-language environment then you have to set proper NLS environment variables on each client.