# Unable to save japanese words in Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to save a form with text fields. When a user enters Japanese characters, the value gets garbled up and stored as ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿. It works fine when I try to save the same field in SQLServer but in Oracle only, it doesn't work. 
While debugging, I can see that the values reach fine on java side. It only garbles up at the time of save.

I have tried changing the characterset in oracle etc, but that did not help. 
I am not even able to save Japanese by using the below query in my sql developer :

```
update ABC_TABLE set DESCRIPTION=N'感がとがとがとがとがと感感感' where id=502;
commit;
```

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37117331/how-to-store-japanese-character-in-oracle-db

Comment: can you please show us your java code? and the way you create your table?

Comment: Did you set up your database to use a compatible encoding, e.g. UTF-8?

Comment: XtremeBaumer - Checked that already. Did not help. But thanks. 
YCF_L - Table is already created in database. Not creating it on the java side. 
Thomas - Below is the configuration in my database : 
NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8MSWIN1252
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16

Comment: Please provide the DDL statement used to create the table.

Comment: Are you using [`setString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,%20java.lang.String)) or [`setNString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNString(int,%20java.lang.String)) in the Java?

Comment: Hi WE8MSWIN1252 will not allow exotic characters.  You need to migrate to UTF8 or preferably AL32UTF8

Comment: @sandman That is the character set the OP is using for `VARCHAR2` columns, they are using `AL16UTF16` for `NVARCHAR2` columns which would support those characters.

Comment: sandman - It was AL32UTF8 only earlier. I changed it to AL16UTF16. 
MT0 - Its using setDescription method in model class, where I am setting this.description = description.

DDL - 
 CREATE TABLE "ABC_TABLE" 
   ( "ID" NUMBER(18,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "DESCRIPTION" NVARCHAR2(255), 
 PRIMARY KEY ("ID")

Comment: what is your NLS_LANG environment variable set to?

Comment: @sandman :  NLS_LANGUAGE AMERICAN

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for helping and suggesting guys. I tried to change the character set back to AL32UTF8(which it was earlier too when i changed it to WE8MSWIN1252) and surprisingly it worked! Its a little wierd since it was not working for me earlier with this configuration. Followed the below link to change it(just in case anyone needs it in future) : [SQL Error: ORA-12712: new character set must be a superset of old character set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352304/sql-error-ora-12712-new-character-set-must-be-a-superset-of-old-character-set)